# Overrides usage in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, overriding

I've got a packages dependency that I need to update, so I've been trying to use [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) in my package.json, however this doesn't seem to work

In my package-lock.json file I can see the following;

```
"node_modules/@babel/core": {
  "version": "7.23.3",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core/-/core-7.23.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "***",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ampproject/remapping": "^2.2.0",
    "@babel/code-frame": "^7.22.13",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/helper-module-transforms": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/helpers": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/parser": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/template": "^7.22.15",
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/types": "^7.23.3",
    "convert-source-map": "^2.0.0",
    "debug": "^4.1.0",
    "gensync": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "json5": "^2.2.3",
    "semver": "^6.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  "funding": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/babel"
  }
},
```

The dependency that I would like to update is this

```
"semver": "^6.3.1"
```

So I have added the following to my package.json

```
"overrides": {
  "semver": "7.5.2"
},
```

I have placed this above my listed dependencies and devDependencies in my package.json file - I'm not sure if it's placement in the package.json is important, I have been unable to find any documentation of that.

I have also tried placing the overrides code at the bottom of my package.json and still have the same issues

I have tried this with several versions of Node 16,17,18,19 and 21

I am currently testing with node 21.2.0 which uses npm v10.2.3 which is above the required v.8.3.0 where overrides were introduced

I've tried deleting the package-lock.json file and the node-modules folder before running npm install ... but everytime I rerun npm install I still end up with the same dependencies used in my package-lock.json file

So currently this feels to me like I am misunderstanding how to use overrides? If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this command

```
npm install semver@7.5.2
```

It  will the override version and update the version of your package in package.json file and update the package in your node modules.

Comment: That will install the package semver directly - I do not have that package installed directly - I only have the semver package being used as a dependency via other packages ... if I run this command it adds the package semver to my package.json which I don't directly need and still leaves me with the issue of other packages dependencies using outdated versions. There is a security vulnerability in versions >7.5.2 which is why I need to remove all dependencies to those versions

Comment: Also just another option would be to update all the packages that are using semver to their latest versions - such as the node_modules/@babel/core mentioned in the original question .. I have done that, that package is using the latest version 7.23.3 which unfortunetly still uses an older version of semver

Comment: This is why I have investigated the option of using overrides